# How does the GDPR apply to processing event bookings?

Tags: gdpr

I am trying to work out if it our business is considered contractual, legitimate interest, or consent under the GDPR.   We are processing event bookings.  The information being collected and processed would be:

- name
- address
- email
- date of birth
- phone

In other words,  just details on how long they want to book for, meals and parking.

Payment info is collected and stored by a third party system.